# How to create a custom content provider for read/write xml files in android sdcard?

Tags: android

From the android developers site it says Content Providers can be used as a layer for working with local db, files, and webservices. There are lots of tuts on the net teaching how to create a Content Provider for Sqlite DB.

I don't want to work work with db rather then working with xml file. I want to create a custom xml content provider which can help me to read/write values in xml file in sdcard directly not via any sqlite stuff. I have reasearched alot but not able to get anything related to xml content provider.

I aleady have a xml file which resides in my mobile sdcard. I am able to read/write without Content Provider but now I want to do it with Content Provider. Please any help will be fruitful.

Comment: What is the point of using a `ContentProvider` to access a file that you can access directly?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/24/o5qx.jpg/ From this images it is clearly visibile that Content Provider is the middle layer for interacting with data. So I want to implement in this fashion only. Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Anyone here who can help me out? Its been a couple of days and no one answering. Waiting for a good response.

Comment: If you want to expose just some parts of the XMLs you have to parse the XML DOM-tree yourself then you can return a custom made MatrixCursor in ContentProvider.query() for the XML-node defined by the uri. But i strongly suggest you to choose SQLite, cause you will face a lot a lot of problems. ContentProviders are simply desined for databases. Simple as that.
But if you want to expose the XMLs as whole raw non-parsed files, you can use Google's FileProvider from the Support library. It works like the Windows file sharing.